# Could not load ruby gem from Puppet provider

Tags: ruby, rubygems, puppet

I'm having some troubles with my modules since I've upgraded from Puppet 3.8 to Puppet 4.2. Looks like it's unable to load gemfiles.
Here is the error message I get:

```
Error: Could not autoload puppet/provider/test/test: cannot load such file -- rest-client
Error: Could not autoload puppet/type/test: Could not autoload puppet/provider/test/test: cannot load such file -- rest-client
Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Could not autoload puppet/type/test: Could not autoload puppet/provider/test/test: cannot load such file -- rest-client at /home/vagrant/tmp/manifests/mytest.pp:1:1 on node
```

I apply the manifest with the command:

```
$ puppet apply manifests/mytest.pp --modulepath=~/tmp/modules/ --debug
```

Here is the manifest code:

```
$ cat manifests/mytest.pp 
test {"mytest": }
```

Provider code:

```
$ cat modules/test/lib/puppet/provider/test/test.rb 
require 'rubygems'
require 'rest-client'

Puppet::Type.type(:test).provide(:test) do
  desc "Just testing"

  def create
    puts "Entered create "
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def exists?
   return false
  end
end
```

Type code:

```
$ cat modules/test/lib/puppet/type/test.rb
Puppet::Type.newtype(:test) do

  @doc = "Just testing."

  ensurable do
    defaultvalues
    defaultto :present
  end

  newparam(:name, :namevar => true) do
    desc 'An arbitrary name used as the identity of the resource.'
  end
end
```

I'm testing on version 1.0.2 of vagrant Box ([centos-6.6-64-puppet](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/puppetlabs/boxes/centos-6.6-64-puppet))

Puppet version:

```
$ puppet --version
4.2.1
```

RubyGems vesion:

```
$ gem --version
1.3.7
```

rest-client gem installed using Yum (rubygem-rest-client.noarch):

```
$ gem which rest-client
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/rest-client.rb
```

Directory structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── manifests
│   └── mytest.pp
└── modules
    └── test
        └── lib
            └── puppet
                ├── provider
                │   └── test
                │       └── test.rb
                └── type
                    └── test.rb
```

Did you have this issue ? any idea how to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found the reason!
Puppet agent is shipped with its own Ruby and Gem binaries, and they lay in /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/

by executing this command:

```
$ facter rubysitedir rubyversion
rubysitedir => /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0
rubyversion => 2.1.6
```

I noticed that it points to a different directory than the standard location.

```
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]
```

To solve the issue, I used the same gem shipped with puppet 4 to install rest-client:

```
sudo /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/gem install rest-client
```